# Python: detect if the parent thread called exit()

Tags: python, multithreading

I have this thread that is running in the background and can be updated from the main thread:

```
import threading
from Queue import Queue
from time import sleep

class Animation(threading.Thread):

    SIGNAL_STOP = 'stop'

    def __init__(self, framerate):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.queue = Queue()
        self.framerate = framerate

    def tell(self, data):
        self.queue.put(data)

    def stop(self):
        self.tell(Animation.SIGNAL_STOP)

    def loop(self):
        # Override this method to implement animation loop
        pass

    def update(self, data):
        # Override this method to implement the state update
        pass

    def cleanup(self):
       # Override this method to implement what's done when the animation is stopped
       pass

    def run(self):
        while True:
            if not self.queue.empty():
                data = self.queue.get()
                if data == Animation.SIGNAL_STOP:
                    break;
                self.update(data)
            self.loop()
            sleep(1. / self.framerate)

        self.cleanup()


class TestAnimation(Animation):
    def __init__(self, framerate):
        super(TestAnimation, self).__init__(framerate)
        self.num = 0

    def loop(self):
        print 'num =', self.num
        self.num = self.num + 1

    def update(self, data):
        print 'update:', data

    def cleanup(self):
        print 'graceful exit'

print 'start'
ta = TestAnimation(1)
ta.start()
sleep(3)
ta.update(123)
sleep(3)
#ta.stop() # I'd like the animation thread to feel that the parent wants to exit and carry out stopping itself
print 'end'
exit()
```

I'd like to implement some way to detect when the parent thread wants to exit and all running threads would then gracefully terminate themselves. I'd prefer that instead of explicitly calling the running thread's stop() method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can just make this a [daemon](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.daemon) thread, so when the main thread exits all the daemonic threads exit with it.

So you can default to `daemon = True` in your constructor or just set it before `start`

```
ta = TestAnimation(1)
ta.daemon = True
ta.start()
```

#### Edit.  Since thread clean up is required.

YOu can use a combination of [`thread.Event`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Event) and [`atexit`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/atexit.html) for signaling to daemon threads to clean up before exiting.

Here is a simple example to do this:

```
import time
import threading
import atexit

signal_to_threads = threading.Event()  # Global signal for threads to stop.

registered_threads = [] # Register all threads into here. 

@atexit.register
def signal_threads():
    print('signaling threads to stop')
    signal_to_threads.set()
    for thread in registered_threads:
        thread.signal.wait()


class TestExit(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        registered_threads.append(self)
        self.signal = threading.Event()
        super(TestExit, self).__init__(*args, **kw)
        self.daemon = True  # Ensure is a daemon thread.

    def run(self):
        while True:
            time.sleep(3)
            print('Hi from child thread')
            if signal_to_threads.is_set():
                print('stopping child thread and doing cleanup.')
                # self.do_cleanup()
                self.signal.set()
                break


t = TestExit()
t.start()
print('sleeping for 10 secs.')
time.sleep(10)
print('exiting main thread')
```

#### Demo:

```
python test_thread.py
sleeping for 10 secs.
Hi from child thread
Hi from child thread
Hi from child thread
exiting main thread
signaling threads to stop
Hi from child thread
stopping child thread and doing clean up.
```

Since `atexit` should run the registered function on exit, no need to keep up with every exit point to clean up threads.

Comment: Ok, but how the background thread can detect that the main thread is exiting, so that it can clean up things?

Comment: @Passiday not sure there is anything simpler than what you are already doing. What is the concern with your approach? (perhaps it can be improved based on the answer)

Comment: @Passiday: You could use a global variable (perhaps in conjunction with a `Lock` to prevent concurrent access) and have the threads check it periodically. Another alternative would be to use a `Queue` to send a "quit" message.

Comment: When I saw that the main thread exit() did not kill the background thread, I was hoping that it could be somehow detected within the thread. I just don't want to have to explicitly call the thread stopping at every point where the main thread could exit. I'd prefer that the threads can do graceful stopping themselves.

Comment: @Passiday Updated answer using `threading.Event` and `atexit` to address your usecase.